# Should rolling back to a previous revision sort question by previous revision date?

Tags: feature-request, sorting, rollbacks

Sometimes, a user will make a very insignificant edit to a very old question/answer. Sorting this question at the top of the active questions queue does more harm than good, as it pushes newer active questions out of view, adds no value to the original question, and brings unnecessary focus to these very old, and often sufficiently answered questions.

I often feel it necessary to rollback these very minor edits as a way of discouraging them, but this only exacerbates the problem by throwing the question, again, to the top of the active questions list.

I'm wondering if this issue could be fixed by **allowing the sort order to be aware of the original revision date when rolling back edits**. This way, a rollback could effectively remove these old, resolved posts to allow newer active posts to stay in view longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of showing activity for edits is to provide a check, so that if an inappropriate edit is applied, users can see that and take an appropriate action (such as reversing the change).  If this were done, then it would allow abusive rollbacks to happen, and to very effectively go unnoticed.  Someone could go around intentionally rolling back useful edits, and others would have a much harder time noticing that they'd done it, if it not only didn't count as activity, but reverted the activity timestamp to an earlier time.

Of course, this process is precisely why people making edits that aren't useful are actually problematic; it fills the activity feed with noise, preventing people from either seeing useful edits that have made significant improvements, or harmful edits requiring reversal.  The fact that there *is* no way of filtering out, "neither useful nor abusive" edits is precisely what makes them problematic.

Comment: That's a good point that I hadn't considered. Is there a proper way to discourage or respond to these trivial edits, or is it simply an inevitable downside?